# -ErrorAction strange behaviour when setting variable from COM object

Tags: vba, powershell, ms-word

I am writing a PowerShell script that takes values from tables in a DOCX file, but I've encountered a little problem. I cannot "silently continue" execution of the script if a DOCX file does not contain any tables or if a table is too small to have a cell with "1,9" coordinates.

Here is the code I have ATM, but it doesn't act the way I expected (errors are still displayed):

```
$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$word.Visible = $false
$document = $word.Documents.Open("C:\document.docx")
Set-Variable -Name "valueInCell" -Value $document.Tables.Item(1).Cell(1,9).Range.Text -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$document.Close()
$word.Quit()
```

Any ideas on how I can silently continue when errors occur?

Comment: What errors? `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` doesn't necessarily suppress all errors (parameter errors for instance).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Something similar to 'Exception calling "Cell" with "2" argument(s): "requested member of the collection does not exist"'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-ErrorAction` parameter controls the handling of errors raised by the command in question - not errors occuring *before* the command is executed.

Before `Set-Variable` is invoked, PowerShell will need to evaluate the value expression `$document.Tables.Item(1).Cell(1,9).Range.Text`, which will surely raise a `InvokeMethodOnNull` error.

Change the default error action preference in the current scope instead:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
Set-Variable varname -Value $null.GetType() # no error output
```

or wrap it in a try/catch block:

```
$valueInCell = try{
    $document.Tables.Item(1).Cell(1,9).Range.Text
} 
catch{
    ""
}
```